# "ain't … nobody" or "ain't … anybody"?

Tags: spoken-english, informal-language, multiple-negation, negative-concord

I just watched a TV show and the guy says:

> I ain't trying to fight with nobody with a baby.

So here, I can't understand the "nobody" since it make no sense to me, but it sounds like anybody, and if it's "I ain't trying to fight with anybody with a baby." that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Informal English sometimes uses what's called a "double negative" for emphasis, putting words like "ain't" and "nobody" together to reinforce how strong the negative is. ("Negative concord" is a more precise, but much less common, term for this.) Here, the quoted character is strongly protesting how little he desires to fight someone with a baby — this would be much less emphatic if he'd just said "I ain't trying to fight with anybody with a baby."

Comment: So both of them make the same sense, but the degree are different

Comment: @JiehongJiang -- The "ain't" marks the dialog as being in a dialect where using "nobody" (in this context) is *more correct* than using "anybody".  It also marks the statement as *not* being Standard English.

Comment: Very good point by @Jasper. If one is going to use the nonstandard *ain't*, the sentence would be weird with *anybody* but it's natural with *nobody*.

Comment: @GoDucks: It's not so much that it's unnatural, but that it's a considerably weaker statement.

Comment: @Nathan I disagree or I wouldn't have said what I said.